# Image uploading via PHP returning empty array

Tags: php

I am unable to successfully upload an image/file to my server. The php is as follows:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$uploadDir = "./";
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)){
    echo "The file has been uploaded successfully.";
} else {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

I chose the directory at which this script lives, to ensure the functionality before I upload to the final directory. I want to upload photo's, and will check for file extensions later - but for now I at least need the upload functionality to work.

I get an empty array returned.

The form is as follows:

```
<form id="imageUploadForm" name="imageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imageController.php">
<label for="photo" class="blogLabel">Upload an Image</label>
<input type="file" name="photo" id="imageUpload">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="imageSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: peek into webserver logs. Can't you run out max upload size?

Comment: Does the upload folder have the proper permissions to write files?

Comment: at the top of imageController.php. put `print_r($_FILES);print_r($_POST);exit()`

Comment: I did that @Dagon and it returned two empty arrays. Which leads me to believe its a permissions thing, or file upload size?

Comment: if either was the case the files array would still be populated. you would just have an error in it. do the error logs or appache logs say anything?

Comment: I forgot to put the `method="POST"` Doh!

Comment: So now my array returned looks OK, but the file still isnt uploading.

Comment: The `print_r($_FILES)` prints this now: `Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => imgres.jpeg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/php1rqFUO [error] => 0 [size] => 15147 ) )`

Comment: @mdance STOP CHANGING YOUR OPs TO COMPLETELY NEW QUESTIONS....

Comment: put the method of form i.e, method="post"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the most important thing about a form -- the `method`!

If there is no method set it defaults to `get`.

You want `post`!

Add `method="post"` to your form.

Comment: @Dagon ha! I keep missing those new comments lol. wth is going on here... my internet is waaaaay too slow....