# PHP - Image uploading not working

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image uploading via PHP returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785726/image-uploading-via-php-returning-empty-array)

I am unable to successfully upload an image/file to my server. The php is as follows:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$uploadDir = "./";
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)){
    echo "The file has been uploaded successfully.";
} else {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

I chose the directory at which this script lives, to ensure the functionality before I upload to the final directory. I want to upload photo's, and will check for file extensions later - but for now I at least need the upload functionality to work.

The form is as follows:

```
<form id="imageUploadForm" name="imageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imageController.php" method="post">
<label for="photo" class="blogLabel">Upload an Image</label>
<input type="file" name="photo" id="imageUpload">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="imageSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
</form>
```

`print_r($_FILES)` returns: `Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => imgres.jpeg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/php1rqFUO [error] => 0 [size] => 15147 ) )`

Comment: What error do you get? Have you set the approprate permissions on your directories?

Comment: How is this question different from the same one you opened a few minutes ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785726/image-uploading-via-php-returning-empty-array

Comment: It is the same, minus some errors. The other guy wanted me to open a new question, rather than edit my original... so I did.

Comment: @j08691 They are different issues.

Comment: Does the `/tmp/php1rqFUO [error] => 0` mean anything?

Comment: make sure imageController.php starts with  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1); move_uploaded_file - should be giving you a warning if the file cant be moved

Comment: I did those error reporting, and it seems as though there is a permissions issue. It says: `Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/imgres.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /**/**/**/**/imageController.php on line 8 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpB25kFk' to 'images/imgres.jpeg' in /**/**/**/**/imageController.php on line 8` Does that mean I need to set permissions in the temporary folder, as well as the folder Im going to actually use?

Comment: make sure the destination folder exist, for test purpose use permission 0777 using chmod command (if you're using *nix system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't have permission to write to that directory. If you're working on a LAMP stack, you need to give the world write access to that directory. From the commandline this is:

```
chmod -R 777 path/to/dir
```

Be careful! You should actually use a different directory than the directory where your script lives. Choose a directory that cannot execute scripts so that someone doesn't upload a script to your site then execute it with full access to your server!